# In MySQL how do I count fields on a table by value in an inner join, then left join those results to a SELECT?

Tags: mysql, join

ok so here's my basic problem.

I'm putting together a site where users can set up ebay searches that I'll automatically perform in the background periodically throughout the day. In my database I have the following 3 tables:

SEARCHES where I store information about the search the user wishes for me to perform.

LISTINGS which are the results specific to that user's search. Basically each row is the id of an ebay item i've found, along with flags for 'new listing', or this listing hidden by user.

ITEM which has all of the information specific to the ebay item (its price, item #, title, if it's still active, etc) this information can be tied to multiple listings since multiple different searches can return the same ebay item.

What I want is to be able to do one db query that lets me take a user id and select all of that user's searches, then for each of those searches include the total number listings (minus any listings they've hidden), the total number of new listings, and the total number of active ebay items tied to each of those searches (making sure to exclude any listings missing their details).

Selecting the searches is trivial, just a simple:

```
SELECT s.* FROM searches s WHERE s.user = ?
```

Getting the count for total, new, and active listings for a specific search can be done with the following select:

```
SELECT
    ifnull( SUM( l.new = 1 ), 0 ) AS new_listings, 
    ifnull( SUM( i.active = 1 ), 0 ) AS active_items, 
    COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM listings l JOIN items i 
    ON l.item = i.item 
    WHERE l.search = ? AND l.hidden = 0
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to merge these two into a single query where each row is the s.* from searches, with the new_listings, active_items, and count columns left joined onto it where the l.search column matches the s.id column.

Can I do this with just joins? Do I need to use a subquery? It's all just a touch over my head.

Thanks!

---

Edit in response to John Ruddell's comment below:

Eeep, sorry about not making the connections between the tables explicit.

The SEARCHES table has a unique ID column that is used to match it with its listings (along with columns for search_keywords, max_price, etc).

Here's an example row from LISTINGS:

```
search | item          | user | added                | new | hidden
-------------------------------------------------------------------
50     | 140696732281  | 2    | 2017-04-07 19:50:01  | 1   | 0
```

Where the listings.search column matches a search.id column.

And here's an example row from ITEMS:

```
item         | title            | img                | price | url               | seller | shipping | active
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
232053821248 | TAIGA SIGNED...  | http://img.ebay... |69.99  | http://www.eba... | ulbop  | 4        | 1
```

Where the listings.item column matches an items.item column

So the query basically goes find all the searches by a matching search.user to a supplied user ID, then match all the listings to the search by matching the search.id to listings.search, finally match all of the items to the the listing table via matching listings.item to the items.item column.

Comment: can you provide some data? where is the correlation between the searches and listings? just the search name?

Comment: Eeep, sorry. Added more example data as requested.

Comment: *.s what's that?

Comment: Me accidently writing s.* backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use aliases.

I am guessing this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *.s FROM searches s WHERE s.user = ?) as foo LEFT JOIN (SELECT
ifnull( SUM( l.new = 1 ), 0 ) AS new_listings, 
ifnull( SUM( i.active = 1 ), 0 ) AS active_items, 
COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM listings l JOIN items i 
ON l.item = i.item 
WHERE l.search = ? AND l.hidden = 0) as foo1
```

Left join on whatever is your joining criteria.

Comment: I thought what you said was clicking into place, but when I tried this it threw an error:

(SELECT *.s FROM searches s WHERE s.user = 2) as search_data LEFT JOIN (SELECT
l.search as search_id
ifnull( SUM( l.new = 1 ), 0 ) AS new_listings, 
ifnull( SUM( i.active = 1 ), 0 ) AS active_items, 
COUNT( * ) AS count 
FROM listings l JOIN details i 
ON l.item = i.item 
WHERE l.hidden = 0) as listings_counts ON search_data.id = listing_counts.search_id

        So I must have gotten something wrong...

Comment: Probably because I missed a select *

Comment: Well, fixing that fixed the error, but the query didn't seem to produce the intended results. In my test db I had a search with three listings. 2 set to new, and 0 set to hidden. Expected results are that the search would have 2 new listings, 3 active items, and a count of 3 In this case it returned new listings 0, active listing 1, and count of 1, so I must have something goofy in there.